# How to extract body of this callback-ish style function using regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to extract body of this function  using JavaScript

```
J_Script(void, someName, (const char *str), {
   function howdy() {
      console.log("What's up");
   }

   howdy();
});
```

I have attempted the following regex,

```
(J_Script\s?)([^\.])([\w|,|\s|-|_|\$]*)(.+?\{)([^\.][\s|\S]*(?=\}))
```

It capture most of it but fails to detect end of the function thus corrputing the end result.

The end result need to looks like this,

```
   function howdy() {
      console.log("What's up");
   }

   howdy();
```

Yes, I know Regex maybe be not perfect for this but I don't have time to create an AST and I'm looking to do some pre-processing using Javascript.

Worth noting that the function will always ends with `});` not `})`

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for the job, but if you can assume that the end of the function is on the beginning of the line, you might be able to hack this in a totally brittle, easily-broken way (I can all but guarantee that's the best you can hope for here, but it might be sufficient for your use case). Can we make that assumption?

Comment: @ggorlen The code file which I am trying to do pre-processing has 5-10 functions like this. I'm not sure what you are asking. The function will always end with });

Comment: I'm asking if we can rely on the tail of the function, `});` always being at character 0 at the start of a line. This makes it relatively easy to match--you slurp lines until you hit `^\}\);` with a multiline flag. Can functions have `});` somewhere inside of them?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes and no I didn't have function inside with });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your function has the substring `});` starting at character 0 at the start of the function closing line (i.e. is flush to the left), you can use

```
(J_Script\s?)([^\.])([\w|,|\s|-|_|\$]*)(.+?\{)([^\.][\s|\S]*?(?=(^\}\);)))
```

With the multiline flag

The only modifications from your original are:

```
(J_Script\s?)([^\.])([\w|,|\s|-|_|\$]*)(.+?\{)([^\.][\s|\S]*?(?=^\}\);))
//                                                          ^   ^
//                                                          |   |
//                                                 non-greedy   beginning of line
```

If your functions have a fixed offset indentation, you can exploit that just the same, using `/^ {x}/` where `x` is a digit representing whatever indentation count you have.

This also handles nested `});` or whatever else might be in the function, so long as it's indented correctly.

If you want to capture the closing `});`, add a capture group to the above pattern:

```
(J_Script\s?)([^\.])([\w|,|\s|-|_|\$]*)(.+?\{)([^\.][\s|\S]*?(?=(^\}\);)))
```

Comment: Tested but NodeJS null while the regex101.com match

Comment: Please show your actual code and exact input. I can't reproduce and fix "NodeJS null" without that information.

Comment: Wait. I need to edit more. It seems working with templated strings while reading from FS seems not..

Comment: I don't know what but if I copy paste the source to an another file it works. I'm on Windows while GIT is in linux mode. Maybe CRLF causing that?

Comment: It works...A little typo caused to return null. .. So sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the lookahead to find the `});` that you always expect at the end:

```regex
(J_Script\s?)([^\.])([\w|,|\s|-|_|\$]*)(.+?\{)([^\.][\s|\S]*(?=(\}\);)))
```

Testbed: https://regex101.com/r/qdsB1w/1/

Comment: @ggorlen then the lookahead should find the last one

Comment: Yeah but then if there are multiple functions together it slurps them all up into one. OP says they have no `});` inside of the function anyway.

Comment: @Keith I tried to match this with NodeJS, like this sourceFile.match(/(J_Script\s?)([^\.])([\w|,|\s|-|_|\$]*)(.+?\{)([^\.][\s|\S]*(?=(\}\);)))/gm); but it return null to me. It works fine in regex101.com tho

Comment: @jeffbRTC the lookahead and groups means there are (I think) 6 groups in the match result. It's odd it works in Regex101 but not nodeJS as both are using the V8 parser (if you visit in Chrome or Edge). I'm afraid I can't help with node issues.

Comment: @Keith it works on Node now. A little typo prevented it from working.